# Monitor memory percentage for azure app service plan

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I'm looking ot monitor the app service plan memory usage as a percentage from grafana but I can't see where this metric is held in log analytics, I can send metrics from the app service but not the plan to log analytics.

Is there any way I can expose this metric outside of azure?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the portal doesn't allow you to set diagnostic settings but you can do this from the backend, I used terraform to add it. I can then get the stats like this in log analytics:

```
AzureMetrics 
| where  ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.WEB" and MetricName == "MemoryPercentage"
```